# Angular setting behaviourSubject default value is not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Lets say i have som behaviour subject with boolean type. And I want that boolean to be true on init.

```
private _someBool: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
get someBool$() {
    return this._someBool.asObservable();
}
```

But the problem is that when I subscribe to it the value is false and I have no idea why. How can i set default value when this approach does not work?

Comment: That can't be right with your example. This code only will get you a `true`. Please share more of it.

Comment: I also tried, it is always `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake there was really place where i was setting it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the observable inside constructor.
You can follow this example:

https://angular-ivy-6bffyy.stackblitz.io